# An error occured: Cannot read property 'stripeId' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

i changed my stripe and firebase api keys and everything back to test mode for some testing purposes. However, I was unpleasantly presented with this error in my console when trying to redirect to checkout using the firebase stripe api:

```
An error occured: Cannot read property 'stripeId' of null
```

however, no where in my code does stripeID exist. interesting. here's the code. oh and keep in mind this only happens in test mode.

```
var userID = "";
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if(user) {
    userID = user.uid
    console.log(user.uid)
}
});


export async function createCheckoutSession(activtyStatus){

  var price = 'price_1Iav0JKDPaWWeL1yBa9F7Aht'
  if (activtyStatus == "canceled") {
   
     // test price
    price = 'price_1IelOCKDPaWWeL1ynps36jkc'
  }
  


      const checkoutSessionRef =  firestore
      .collection('customers')
      .doc(userID)
      .collection('checkout_sessions')
      .add({
        price: price,
        success_url: "https://app.x.com/successPage",
        cancel_url: "https://app.x.com/signin",
    });
    
      // Wait for the CheckoutSession to get attached by the extension
            (await checkoutSessionRef).onSnapshot(function (snap) {
              const { error, sessionId } = snap.data();
              if (error) {
            // Show an error to your customer and 
            // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
              console.log(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
            }
            if (sessionId) {
            // We have a session, let's redirect to Checkout
            // Init Stripe

            const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_test_C');

            console.log("going to stripe: ")

              stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId})
              console.log("logged stripe")
            
          }
      });
    }

export async function goToBilliingPortal(){
  var finalRoute = "https://app.x.com/profile"
  const functionRef = app
  .functions('us-central1')
  .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createPortalLink');
  const {data} = await functionRef({returnUrl : finalRoute});
  window.location.assign(data.url);
};
```

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Surely there's a stacktrace of sorts to at least inform you *where* the error has occurred and what was called up to that point. Can you include that information?

Comment: @DrewReese I only changed the to the test keys, changed the web hooks and restricted keys, as noted by Stripe and firebase. The error in my console is literally just `An error occured: Cannot read property 'stripeId' of null`, if i click on it to get more context, it simply brings me to the source page in my code, showing me the line where I log the error! So strange

Comment: I see, so an error has been detected somewhere and your code is simply console logging it. What is in the `error` object itself? Any other details?

Comment: Had the same issue and turns out that the (testing) customer I was trying to redirect to the portal hadn't subscribed before. After making sure that they've subscribed to a product, I was able to redirect them to the portal.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked what the logs of your Stripe dashboard or Firebase Functions say?
I faced similar issue, and looking at the logs it was because of a failure of the createCheckoutSession function. I was having the following message in my Firebase logs:

> ext-firestore-stripe-subscriptions-createCheckoutSession
> ❗️[Error]: Failed to create customer for [XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]: This API
> call cannot be made with a publishable API key. Please use a secret
> API key. You can find a list of your API keys at
> https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys.

I simply had to replace the key in "Stripe API key with restricted access" in Firebase console with a restricted key and it was solved.

Answer (score 1):

The restricted key is used in the extension config,
the publishable pk is used in your javascript stripe initialization,
and secret sk is used in your session request like:
api_key: 'sk_live ...'

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, for me it was that my card was declined by google clouds since my card eas expired. I updated my account with another card and no more issues.

Comment: This has nothing to do with GCP's billing systems.

Comment: Well it did for me, and fixed my issue